# 3 person Knights and Knaves Problem

Tags: logic, puzzle

The problem goes as such: politicians never tell the truth and non politicians always tell the truth. A stranger meets 3 natives and asks the first of them "Are you a politician?" And he answers. The second native then reports that the first native denied being a politician. The third native says that the first native is a politician. How many of these 3 are politicians?

I'm essentially confused on how to solve this problem without knowing what the 1st native said.

Comment: To get oriented in the problem, just go case by case.  Can all three be politicians?  Can all three be non-politicians?  There are only $8$ cases so you can do this exhaustively if you can't think of anything else.

Comment: Side note:  you do know what the first one said, or at least you can figure it out.  What does he reply if he is politician?  What does he reply if he isn't?

Comment: You *do* know what 1 said.  1 said what everyone says when you ask them "Are you a liar".   Does anyone ever say "Yes, I am a liar"?  Who'd say that?

Answer (score 5):

Case 1:  No. 1 is a liar.

"Are you a liar?"

No. 1 think.  "Hmm, I am but I better lie" and says "No, I'm not".  That's a lie.

No. 2 says "No. 1 denied it".  That's true.

No. 3 says "No. 1 is a liar".  That's true.

You have one liar.

Case 2: No. 1 is not a liar.

"Are you a liar?"

No.1 thinks "No.  I'm not and I better tell the truth" and says "No, I'm not". That's true.

No. 2 says "No. 1 denied it".  That's true.

No. 3 says "No. 1 is a liar".  That's a lie.

You have 1 liar.

So... You have one liar.  Either 1 is a liar and 3 is a truther.  Or 1 is a truther and 3 is a liar.  2 is definitely a truther.

Comment: Could perhaps add some insight into how you came up with this argument/proof?  For example, why did you do a case split, and why did you choose do this on whether or not no. 1 is a liar?  Perhaps that would help the OP...  Thanks!

Comment: Insight?  I didn't have *ANY* insight.  I just imagined myself in the situation and tried to consider what would happen.  I ask a person "Are you a liar"  and imagine what s/he would respond... well, that depends on if s/he *is* a liar so I considered each case.

Answer (score 1):

Let's write $\;P(x)\;$ for "$\;x\;$ is a politician".  We are told that, when $\;x\;$ says $\;\phi\;$, then $\;\phi\;$ is true if and only if $\;x\;$ is not a politician.  That is,
$$
\lnot P(x) \equiv \underline{\phi}
$$
(where I've underlined $\;x\;$'s statement for clarity, this line does not have any formal meaning).

Naming the politicians $\;A,B,C\;$ in order, the second's statement translates to
$$
\tag{1} \lnot P(B) \equiv \underline{(\lnot P(A) \equiv \underline{\lnot P(A)})}
$$
Now simplify the right hand side, and the conclusion about $\;B\;$ is...?

For the third, we get
$$
\lnot P(C) \equiv \underline{P(A)}
$$
What does this tell us about the combination of $\;A\;$ and $\;C\;$?

Add up those sub-answers and you get your answer.

---

The nice thing about this style of proof is that there is no need for any case analysis, which (in my opinion) makes the argument clearer.